# Where does the outdated "thing-O-thing" come from?

Tags: etymology

In many an outdated medium one may come across words such as *gram-O-phone* or *shear-O-matic*.

**Where does this 'tradition' of having the *O* seperated** come from?

Does this stylistic choice have name? I've tried searching the web for answers but my efforts where fruitless.

Examples of this form of writing would be:

> In 1904, the company received its charter as the Berliner Gram-o-phone Company of Canada.

*From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_Gramophone#Foreign_Interests)*

Comment: Gramophone is a word, without splitting out the O. This isn't the same for shear-o-matic.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes, but I have seen it written as such, I shall see if I can find a source.

Comment: Well that's odd. It's really a rough inversion of phonogram

Comment: Completely not an answer, but tangentially related and possibly something that might be borne out by a proper answer, but I think the -o- is an American thing. In the UK we had a children's TV programme: "Melvin and Maureen's Music-a-grams". Maybe -a- is the BrE equivalent of the AmE -o-?

Comment: Shear-O-matic is obviously a pun on 'automatic'. I suppose when mechanical devices for doing particular tasks were first invented and trade names for them were coined, the 'new' element of the word was separated to make it stand out.

Comment: @AndyT What an interesting thought! I've never seen that, and the Wallace & Gromit inventions are also often labeled with an '-O-matic'. I wonder whether it cones from 'automatic' being pronounced with an unstressed 'o', making it closer to an 'a' in sound.

Comment: Also see ["the Fishing Rod-O-Matic"](https://runescape.wiki/w/Fishing_rod-o-matic)

Comment: @Cascabel Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: The _-o-_ in those two words have different paths, but they both ultimately go back to the Greek **thematic vowel**. If you look that up, you’ll have a good starting point.

Comment: @Cascabel Your fishing rod appears to be broken.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Don't give up...It's my bad, I often have difficulty with humor and sarcasm. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure how I segued over to Tim Vine's 'jokeathon', but this candidate (it's had such a large audience that it can't be summarily discounted) word appears with various hyphenation schemes. Though it's certainly a portmanteau involving marathon, the variant joke-a-thon (which also appears in other contexts) follows the X-a-Y model.

Comment: The BernzOmatic torch dates to 1876. I figured the O was Otto Bernz, the founder. [BernzOmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BernzOmatic). The other that came to mind was Spark O Matic, 1953, apparently, but I think the phrase may have had ather, earlier uses predating the company.

Comment: The Ford O Matic tranny (later known as Cruise O Matic) was deployed in 1951.

Comment: Perhaps the earliest model for this type of construction was something like _Tam o' Shanter_ (Burns) where the o' was a poetic shortening of 'of'. Also _will-o'-the-wisp_ (1660s, [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/will-o'-the-wisp)) and _Jack-o'-Lantern_. _Etch A Sketch_ is rather later.

Comment: Ronco used the X-O-Matic form a lot, starting in 1964. Veg-O-Matic, Chop-O-Matic, and Dial-O-Matic were a few of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronco#Inventions The form also showed up in Looney Tunes and Tom & Jerry cartoons: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22looney+tunes%22+O-matic&t=ffsb&ia=web

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Let's not forget Dan Ackroyd"s *bass-o-matic*. Then there's the Fonz's *perfectamundo*, which is something else we again.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts and research on this:
My first thought is it originated with the corporate advertising world. Then i thought, what’s old with an o in the middle. Gramophone! So I looked it up. American Heritage says it was originally a trademark for a Phonograph. Both words have an o in the middle and date to the late 1800s. The OED provided an interesting further possible clue: “origin, late 19th century : formed by inversion of elements of phonogram, a sound recording. The trademark gramophone is phonogram backwards. Easy enough from there to emphasize the O in the middle for advertising. It’s also easy to imagine the successful gramophone/phonogram inspiring copycat use by other firms with new gadgets to adopt the O - a 20th century ad meme before the word meme was coined. As others have noted, automatic provides a similar explanation, especially for kitchen gadgets, borrowing the O and adding the matic. 
It seems logical, but what I don’t know is if there are any examples earlier than gramophone/phonogram and variant phonograph.

Comment: why should we believe you?  Please back up your answer with cited sources.